# WPF UI Window not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, splash-screen

I have a window which contains a label and an animated spinner. This window is a kind of splash screen saying "Loading...".

It is a simple basic window:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWin.SplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    <!-- Grid and within the label at row 0, and the spinner at row 1 -->
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Loading...</Label>  
    <Grid Name="mySpinner" Grid.Row="1"></Grid>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

**Code behind**:

```
public partial class SplashScreen: Window
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        // Here I instantiate the spinner control and show in UI 
        UCSpinner myUCSpinner = new UCSpinner();

        host.Child = myUCSpinner;
        this.mySpinner.Children.Add(host);
    }
}
```

The animated spinner is a control that is instantiated and loaded in the window load event: Window_Loaded

Then from my main wpf window, I have a button.  When button is clicked I create a background worker, I start the background worker and after that I call the splash window above indicated. See below.

**Main window button**:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Width="75" Command="{Binding LaunchOperationCommand}" Content="Calculate" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
</Button>
```

**Code behind**:

```
        RelayCommand launchOperationCommand;
        public ICommand LaunchOperationCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (launchOperationCommand== null)
                    launchOperationCommand= new RelayCommand(param => this.DoLongOperation(), param => true);

                return launchOperationCommand;
            }
        }


        private void DoLongOperation()
        {
            BWorker = null;

            if (BWorker == null)
            {
                BWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                BWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
                BWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;

                BWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BWorker_LongOp_DoWork);
                BWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BWorker_LongOp_ProgressChanged);
                BWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BWorker_LongOp_RunWorkerCompleted);
            }

            if (BWorker.IsBusy != true)
            {
                BWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                ShowSplashScreen();
            }
        }

        private System.Windows.Window splashWindow = null;
        private void ShowSplashScreen()
        {
            if (splashWindow == null)
            {
                splashWindow = new SplashScreen();
            }

            if (splashWindow .IsVisible == false)
                splashWindow .ShowDialog();
        }
```

The problem is the following: The label in the splash screen is displayed but the spinner not.

Comment: do you really need WindowsForms spinner? Why not ProgessBar styled to be a cricle?

Comment: What is `UCSpinner`?

Comment: I think your problem might be in the UCSpinner control.  Try (temporarily) replacing it with something else from System.Windows.Forms.  If that works then UCSpinner must not be compatible with what you're doing here.  There are plenty of WPF spinner/progress bar styles available, though.  Using a WinForms control would not be my first choice.

Comment: @Sinatr It is a user controls that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control.

Comment: Seems the problem is that splash screen called from button click event is blocking UI thread. I am using the same in other parts within other events (not button click) and it is working but through button click event isn't.

Comment: So what can I do? any ideas? why from button click event is not working and from other events, for example, datagrid row selected event is?